# If iText PdfGraphics2D.create() is used, absolute drawing order is not respected in generated PDF

Tags: java, swing, pdf-generation, itext

I'm having trouble using iText's PdfGraphics2D to create PDFs from Swing components with Nimbus LAF.  After some investigation, I think it's due to creation of multiple Graphics objects and subsequent out-of-order use.

Unlike Swing Graphics2D, if iText's PdfGraphics2D.create() is used to generate a new PdfGraphics2D object, the order of PdfGraphics2D object creation affects the order in which components are drawn, rather than just using the absolute order in which a draw method is called.  (See code example below - note that it's **not** using Nimbus.  This is a general problem, it's just more acute in Nimbus.)

My question: Is this fixable?  Or do I have to give up on using Nimbus if I want to generate PDFs?

I'm a total novice when it comes to PDFs and iText.  Am I missing a setting that would force the PDF drawing order to be the same as the Swing drawing order, regardless of the order in which Graphics objects are created?  (It's not writer.setStrictImageSequence(true) - I tried that just in case.)

The following frame looks different when displayed with Swing vs used to generate a PDF with PdfGraphics2D:

```
public class TestFrame extends JFrame {

    public TestFrame() {
        TestPanel panel = new TestPanel();
        add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                TestFrame frame = new TestFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setVisible(true);

                Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);
                try {
                    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("TestFrame.pdf"));
                    writer.setStrictImageSequence(true);
                    document.open();
                    PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
                    PdfGraphics2D graphics = new PdfGraphics2D(canvas, PageSize.LETTER.getWidth(), PageSize.LETTER.getHeight());
                    frame.paint(graphics);
                    graphics.dispose();
                    document.close();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Created PDF");
                }
                catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println("Error creating PDF");
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    class TestPanel extends JPanel {

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            Graphics2D g4 = (Graphics2D) g2.create();
            Graphics2D g3 = (Graphics2D) g2.create();

            g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            Rectangle leftBar = new Rectangle(0, 0, 50, 200);
            // Should be drawn first
            g2.fill(leftBar);

            g3.setColor(Color.RED);
            g3.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 12));
            Rectangle topBar = new Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 50);
            // Should be drawn second
            g3.fill(topBar);

            g4.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            Rectangle rightBar = new Rectangle(150, 0, 50, 200);
            // Should be drawn third
            g4.fill(rightBar);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            // Size panel to drawing for convenience
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }
}
```

With Swing, the rectangles are drawn in the order the fill methods are called: left, top, right.  With PdfGraphics2D, the order is reversed because of the order in which the graphics objects are created.

In Nimbus LAF, presumably because painters are used to draw borders and/or backgrounds, multiple Graphics objects are created and used out-of-order when drawing certain components.  For example, a JTextField with the default border is covered with a black bar in the resulting PDF, as seen in this old StackOverflow question:

[Why is iText's PdfWriter printing JTextFields black when exported as a runnable jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12048610)

It's never answered, and OP never explicitly says they're using Nimbus, but that's exactly what I see.  I also see problems when using JButton and JComboBox.

As an aside, I'd bet this issue is also causing the overlap in this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29410971

**EDIT**

Sorry, I definitely should have spent more time looking at how PDFs and iText work!

As @Bruno Lowagie rightly said, iText doesn't decide how to draw things.  (Thank you Bruno, you made me realize I needed to check my assumptions and look at the code!)

I incorrectly assumed that PdfGraphics2D was generating the PDF instructions, but I (finally) understand that it's using the underlying PdfContentByte to do so, with actual content stored in an internal ByteBuffer.  Since creation of a new PdfGraphics2D also creates a duplicate PdfContentByte (which makes sense, to ensure state changes stay separate), you can't interleave drawing instructions from different PdfGraphics2D objects in the resulting PDF.

So, sadly for me, Nimbus may be out if you need to convert Swing displays to PDFs.

Comment: Are you sure the order in which things drawn on different `Graphics2D` instances of the same canvas eventually appear has been specified somewhere? Maybe it is undefined and implementation-specific...

Comment: Which version of iText are you using?

Comment: @Bruno Lowagie I tried with both 5.5.5 and the new 5.5.6.

Comment: @mkl Hmm you may be right, I don't know if there's a specification for that.  But it does make it a little difficult to use iText's PdfGraphics2D if it doesn't draw items in the same order as Swing.

Comment: iText doesn't decide how to draw items! `PdfGraphics2D` is nothing more than an implementation of the abstract class `java.awt.Graphics2D`. It accepts its instructions from outside iText.

Comment: True, sorry!  I don't mean to imply that it decides how to draw things, I (or Java's Nimbus) give the appropriate instructions.  But would you say it's responsible for translating the Java instructions into PDF commands?  (I'm not sure what the correct name would be, sorry, I know very little about PDFs.)  I guess essentially I'm wondering if there's something I can do to ensure that the eventual PDF drawing commands are executed by a renderer (eg Adobe Reader) in the same order as the original Graphics2D calls were made.

Answer (score 0):

[Orson PDF](http://www.object-refinery.com/orsonpdf/index.html) (GPLv3 or commercial license) provides a `PDFGraphics2D` implementation that we've tested using the SwingSet3 application and the Nimbus Look and Feel and it works well.  You should download version 1.7 (or later) and try it.